# How to test managed code that depends on native dll using MSTest V2

Tags: c#, unit-testing, native, mstest, csproj

We're migrating all our C# test projects from MSTest V1 to MSTest V2. Some of our tested projects depend on native dlls. In the past we could just add an ItemGroup as below to the test project:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="some_path\some_native.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

But after we'move moved to MSTest V2, we're getting the following error while running tests.

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'some_native.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Adding a `DeploymentItem` attribute above the test class or test method has no effect.

We're using:

- Windows 10 x64
- .NET Framework 4.8
- Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK 17.0.0
- MSTest.TestFramework 2.2.8
- MSTest.TestAdapter 2.2.8

So basically my question is: how to test a project A, that depends on a native dll B.dll, using MSTest V2?